# What resistor do I need to turn a 6 volt current into a 5 volt current?

Tags: voltage, resistors

I am trying to mod a ECS-10 Modulus Nerf Gun to include a laser sight, and since the laser I am using runs at 5 volts, but the battery is 4 AA, what resistor should I use to convert the power?

Comment: You need to know the *current* going through the resistor to drop 1 volt. BTW, it might be easier to use NiCd or NiMH cells, which will be closer to 5 volts and are rechargeable.

Comment: A typical alkaline battery goes from 1.5V (fully charged) to about 1.0V (20% charged, under load). So your voltage goes from 6V down to 4V. You will need a device that adapts to the input voltage and can both increase and reduce the voltage, e.g. a buck-boost converter.

Comment: Does the laser have a range for input volts?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the laser module?  No laser really works at 5V, so your module must already have some kind of current regulation to work at 5V.  The datasheet for the module should tell you the acceptable range of input voltage.  It can probably handle more than just 5V, but the only way to tell for sure is to check the datasheet.

Comment: Zener diode can do that. If you need a higher current then use a BJT (emitter follower configuration). And include the link of the datasheet of the laser.

Answer (score 1):

Because the current need of the laser unknown, it is better to drop the voltade with a 1N4007 Diode, it drops the voltage by 0,7v to 1,0 volt depending on the current draws by the laser. Anode connect to + of bettery, Cathode to the Laser (+) terminal.

Comment: 4 x AA Alkaline new = 6.5V. Near end of life ~= 4V.  . A diode is too cude for this application.

Answer (score 1):

Use a linear regulator, with a reasonably low dropout. You can dead bug a through-hole one easily and cover the whole thing in heat shrink. An example of one that is (likely) suitable is the LM2931. You'll probably want to add another cell or two, since your pack can still output useful current below the dropout voltage of a 5V linear regulator. If you *must* use a 4 cell pack, you could try purchasing an off the shelf buck-boost converter module.